# How do I know if an app or a game has been optimized for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, 7.5, 7.8

Of course, if an app or a game is only for Windows Phone 8, it is (or should have been) optimized for Windows Phone 8.

But what about apps or games available for both Windows Phone 7 and 8? How do I know if it is optimized, particularly, for high resolution?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything saying this. Actually the developer many times mention that the app is optimized to Windows Phone 8 if it is.

In the Store you can see if the app is compatible with WP8 but it not guarantee that it is optimized.